How to create an ALTO file from existing data?

I want my program to output an ALTO file. I have all data needed to create it, so I'm wondering if there already exists some code that I can deploy that creates the ALTO file, instead of coding it myself. 

I already looked for conversions, but can only find ones between OCR output formats, like hOCR to ALTO, PAGE to ALTO etc. I'm looking for something like raw data to ALTO, or JSON to ALTO, or csv to ALTO, etc etc. 

The information I have (and that would be needed for creating an ALTO file) is:

all of the words on a page, split by textblock and textline, each with corresponding ID.
the content of the words
the coordinates of words, lines and blocks (hpos, vpos, width and height)
the word confidence for each word


You can use tesseract to create an ALTO file.
The command line is:
tesseract input.png outputfilename --alto

You will find than your alto file outputfilename.xml.
